# Where the NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT is set at client side?

Tags: oracle

I want to know where does this parameter gets set?

I cannot make connection and then set this parameter as I have to use it in a script to execute procs.

`$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` or `$ORACLE_HOME/databases` does not exist and `init.ora` file is not present anywhere.

I have tried to first set this parameter at shell level and then make connection and execute proc, but that does not works.

Ultimately I want this parameter to be `'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SSXFF AM'`.

Please help determine where it is set or let me know if I can set some variables at shell level so that it is set in oracle session by default to
`'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SSXFF AM'`.

It is oracle DB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

first off, it's not NLS_TIMESTAMP_PARAMETER, but NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.

yes, it is an environment variable, set at the os session level. It doesn't go in any init files.  Unfortunately, no one was looking over your should to see *exactly* what you did when you "tried to first set this parameter at shell level and then make connection and execute proc".  But if I had a shell script that called sqlplus, I would:

```
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=<whaterver format mask you want>
export NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT
sqlplus ........
```